# Payflow API: Error 37: Invalid Recurring profile ID

Tags: paypal

I'm a bit stucked on getting Recurring profile details from Payflow via API.

We do regular inquiry:

```
TRXTYPE=R
&TENDER=C
&PARTNER=PayPal
&VENDOR=merchant
&USER=user
&PWD=password
&ACTION=I
&ORIGPROFILEID=RP000000014
```

But in respond we get Error 37: Invalid recurring profile ID.

But this is impossible, as this is exact Recurring profile ID. Which is on LIVE mode, and we do request o live mode for sure.

When searching this profile ID in web-interface in our payflow account it finds it well, but not via API.

Answer (score 0):

Likely problem:
The error usually means that the Recurring Profile id (in this case, RP000000014) does not exist.

Something to consider:
The only thing I see that is different from my working set up is the order in which you sent the name-value-pairs. I have only ever sent the PARTNER/VENDOR/USER/PWD pairs *before* the recurring account pairs.

Good luck!